# what do i do to fix my Mongodb connection error

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mongodb to set up a database, however i keep encountering an error?

Ive tried redownloading mongo and updating ubuntu but keet getting the error

MongoDB shell version v4.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-04-24T16:27:11.186+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: Are u directly running mongo because in most of the cases u have to run mongod first then mongo (some times mongod doesn't start automatically first)

Comment: So i am opening a console and sudo mongod start, then opening a second console and putting mongo and the above error is happening

Comment: I get same error when i stop my mongo service from services in windows but i believe u are on Ubuntu. I'll try to look around because i generally dont use Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its an error caused due to some kind of permissions .

```
                                   (OR)
```

Checkout if the used  username and the password is  correct or not !

Comment: See that word , connection refused , it means that your application can communicate with your db but it doesn't gets access to tables and data

Comment: That's strange because i've used mongo on these machines before an its worked fine. Im trying to start a new database